# Open XBMC or similar apps on secondary monitor

Tags: kodi

I wanted to use xmbc, zinc or similar media center apps on my computer.

Problem is, that my computer uses the TV monitor as secondary screen.

WMC (windows media center) knows to open in full screen on the TV, but I can't seem to convince xmbc or any other free open media center to do the same. anyone knows how to do it? I can't change the comptuers settings (switch primary screens) every time I want to use a media center app...

so for now, WMC is the only option for me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an application called XBMCLaunch or [use Ultramon](http://www.xbmc.org/forum/showthread.php?t=38294&highlight=ultramon) to run XBMC on a secondary monitor/TV.

Comment: It somehow doesn't maximize XBMC if your first monitor is e.g. 600x800 and your second monitor is 1024x768